# Slack Enterprise list all files/conversations

Tags: api, slack

is it possible to list all of the conversations in my slack organization using the API?
Or for the very least, within a workspace.

When I tried calling the "conversations.list" endpoint using a token with an enterprise token, I got an "enterprise_is_restricted" error.

When I invoked the same endpoint with a workspace token, I got a list of all of the public channels, and IM's that I'm a member of, but private conversations that my user (the primary owner) is not a member of were not retreived. Now it makes sense that I wouldn't be able to read them, but I'm looking for a way to list them, to get their name and members basically.

And than with files. I got the same "enterprise_is_restricted" error when I used my enterprise app token, and when I used a specific workspace token, I only got files that were shared with me. I want to be able to keep track of what files are being shared and with whom (for information security reasons), so this is very problemetic for me.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Only the DiscoveryAPI can do that

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. The following should give you at least permissions to all conversations within the workspace.

1. Generate an OAuth Access Token for your Slack app
   [image]
2. Go to api.slack.com to set permissions for it. This particular method needs the following scopes: "channels:read,groups:read,mpim:read,im:read"
   [image]
3. Install/reinstall the app and use that OAuth token to access your list of conversations
   [image]

Comment: It does not retrieve private conversations that you are not a member of.

Comment: Yes you will need to use the discovery API for private conversations